# How to check if attribute set exist in Magento?

Tags: magento, attributes

How to check by name if there is an attribute set?
I need to know if it's already created or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get all the details of the attribute set by attribute-set name.

```
$attributeSetName = "default"; // put your own attribute set name
$attribute_set = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")->getCollection();
$attribute_set->addFieldToFilter("attribute_set_name", $attributeSetName)->getFirstItem();
echo $attribute_set->getAttributeSetId();
```

Answer (score 1):

search by name and compare:

```
if(Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("attribute_set_name", $name)->getFirstItem()->getAttributeSetId() === NULL)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with if your attribute its created should be in catalog_resource_eav_attribute

`$m = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
    ->loadByCode('catalog_product',$code);`

```
if(null===$m->getId()) {
    //attribute does not exist
    echo "//ERROR: Attribute code: *".$code."* does not exists\n";
    return false;
```

}

Comment: Attribute set is different to attribute